# How to update JAVA SDK using command prompt

Tags: java, sdk, java-7

[image]

I have JAVA SDK 1.7.0.170 installed on my windows 7, I need to upgrade to 1.7.0.250. Is there a command line option?

Any equivalent of PIP for python updates?

Comment: Why -1? You have an answer? Getting installer from Oracle is known option, but what if I wanted to automatically install updates whenever it is available?

Comment: I did not downvoted. I don't know who did.

Comment: I do not have the Update option enabled in the Java control panel.

Answer (score 5):

Not really. But what you can do is to install Java on one computer and then ZIP the folder where the files were installed. To install on all the other computers, just unzip the archive, set `JAVA_HOME` and change the `PATH` variable.

If that's too much work to do manually, you can try to create a custom installer.

Note that this might violate the EULA; if you do this for a company, have legal check this.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this from the command line for Oracle's JDK as you must accept their license agreement on their web site before you can download.

You could download and install the latest OpenJDK using `wget` and run the installer. (two commands)  You would need to change your environment settings which might be possible using a command line regedit, but I always use the windows configuration for this.

Comment: I agree this could have been an alternative given that the download location remains same. But for Java JDK this location would differ for every new version.

Comment: @Karthick Of course, you don't want to be downloading a random version.  You want specific one ;)